# looking for a simple http response with an image coded in base64

Tags: image, http, base64

I was playing around with basic4android and and tried to create a simple webserver. Everything fine but somehow I didn't manage to send an image as binary file. I found the problem and everything is ok now but in the meantime I was desperate and thought I could send a binary file as text coded in base64. I am still busy with that idea but cannot find proper information how a valid http response would look like with a base64 encoded image.

I guess it should look similar to something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: lengthofthefollowingdata

dataofimagecodedinbase64
```

Can someone post a proper working example?

Do the standard browsers accept images coded in base64?

Comment: I don't think the browser can accept base64 encoded images buffer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no base64 encoding in HTTP responses. It would be *possible* (but useless) to define it as new Transfer-Coding or Content-Coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this, what I just found would not work? [link](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=89663.0)

Comment: Now I found another source, where base64 encoding is used. Are you saying that this wouldn't work: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299277/browser-not-recognizing-image-sent-by-home-brew-server-in-java)

Comment: I don't believe it works, unless you have a client that implements that content encoding (which I do not think anybody does).

Answer (score 0):

lets take the $base64string var as example loading in it and image file by this way:

```
$base64string = base64_encode(file_get_contents("image.jpg"));
```

first u got to do is set the content type by this php code:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg") //if your data is format jpeg
```

if your data is stored as base64 so you will have to decode it by this code:

```
$decoded_data = base64_decode($base64string);
```

then all you have to do is write the decoded data by an echo.

```
echo $decoded_data;
```

Optionally: if you want to insert an image in HTML or CSS u dont have to decode the base64 string... example:

HTML IMG TAG:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $base64string; ?>" alt="image" />
```

CSS INLINE BACKGROUND PROPERTY:

```
style="background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $base64string; ?>';"
```